# Comparing lists via (unsorted) graphs?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I have a list (of lists) and like to identify elements that have the same "structure"! Here is a minimal example:

`example = { {{m1,m2},{m2,m4}} , {{m1,m2},{m1,m4}} }`

This list has two elements `{{m1,m2},{m2,m4}}` and `{{m1,m2},{m1,m4}}` (which both are lists again). Now, in the problem I am working on each element is associated to a product of Kronecker deltas according to

`{{m1,m2},{m2,m4}}` -> $\delta_{m1,m2} \delta_{m2,m4}$

with $\delta_{i,j}$ the Kronecker delta. In that sense, `{{m1,m2},{m2,m4}}` and `{{m1,m2},{m1,m4}}` are **mathematically identical** (have the "same structure").

**Question:** How can I write a Mathematica code that identifies these elements as the same and returns me a new list, where each element with the same structure appears only once together with its "multiplicity" in the original list?

My (failed) solution: I thought I could work with graphs and associate graphs `G1` and `G2` to `{{m1,m2},{m2,m4}}` and `{{m1,m2},{m1,m4}}`, respectively, with corresponding edges as indicated by the pairs. Then, `G1` and `G2` literally look the same, yet when I try

`Tally[{G1,G2}]`

I do not get `{G1,2}`, but `{{G1,1},{G2,1}}`. So somehow Mathematica is unable to identify graphs with the "same structure" as the same.

How can I solve the problem? Any hint is greatly appreciated! Many thanks!

**Edit in response to comments:**

The example above is a real sample list: m1, m2, ... are indices that never take on any numerical value. I just want to order them according to the structure I mentioned. The full code I tried is

```
Test = {{{m1, m2}, {m2, m4}}, {{m1, m2}, {m1, m4}}}; 
graphs = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[Test], i++,
 mvert = {m1, m2, m3, m4};
 medges = 
  Table[Test[[i, j]][[1]] <-> Test[[i, j]][[2]], {j, 1, 
    Length[Test[[1]]]}];
 graphs = Append[graphs, {Graph[mvert, medges]}];
 ]
Tally[graphs]
```

but it doesn't work. I think `Dimensions` and `CountsBy` also will not do the job, `GroupBy` might help but it seems complicated to find the right function according by which to group (that's why I used the graph method because I thought that's the best idea).

Comment: Have you tried `Dimensions` ?

Comment: Could you include a sample list explicitly? Have you tried [`CountsBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountsBy.html), or [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html)?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `Tally` looks for structural identity, where you only care about whether the connected components are the same. To fix it, you can explicitly group graphs by their connected components (note that I have slightly modified the definition of `graphs` to remove one level of lists):

```
mvert = {m1, m2, m3, m4};
graphs = Graph[mvert, UndirectedEdge @@@ #] & /@ Test

GatherBy[graphs, Map[Sort]@*ConnectedComponents]
(* {{Graph[...], Graph[...]}} *)
```

The `Map[Sort]` part is to ensure that the individual vertices are properly sorted - this is probably not necessary, but the documentation doesn't guarantee that they are indeed sorted

Comment: Thank you very much! I think the command `ConnectedComponents` was precisely what I was missing!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, the following GroupBy approach may work. I expanded your example to include a "different" entry that would not be equivalent to the first two, so we can have meaningful counts:

```
example = { 
   {{m1, m2}, {m2, m4}},
   {{m1, m2}, {m1, m4}},
   {{m1, m1}, {m2, m2}} 
 };

Values@
 Map[First[#] -> Length[#] &]@
  GroupBy[example, (And @@ SameQ @@@ # &)]

(* Out:
{
  {{m1, m2}, {m2, m4}} -> 2,
  {{m1, m1}, {m2, m2}} -> 1
}
*)
```

Comment: This also works, thanks a lot! Unfortunately, the true list I have is a little more involved. Since I am also unfortunately not able to get the gist of your idea/coding, I think I go with the `ConnectedComponents` idea from Lukas Lang.